# Java Array in a constructor is not working

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

A strange thing happened to me which I am not able to explain to myself, so I hope someone can explain it to me.
The situation is the following: I have an class called "Item". Instances of these class are instantiated with a name and two integer arrays, representing some values for this item (the meaning of these values are not important for this).

This works:

```
private Item item = new Item("Something", null, null);
```

This isn't:

```
private Item item = new Item("Something", {"A", "B"}, null);
```

This however works:

```
private String[] str = {"A", "B"};
private Item item = new Item("Something", str, null);
```

So.. my question is: Why? I absolutelty don't see why the second method isn't possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler doesnt automatically know the type of the array so it has to be expressly defined when declaring it as an expression

```
private Item item = new Item("Something", new String[] {"A", "B"}, null);
```

Comment: Oh well, that actually does make sense! Thank you.